# Loss of developer ergonomics after packaging code as library

Tags: npm, webpack, visual-studio-code

I have made a few applications (using webpack, babel, react, d3, npm etc.) that uses very similar charting code.  I am in the process of splitting out that charting code into an npm package which multiple apps can then import.

To test this out, I've embedded a demo app inside my chart libraries project directory and install the library at its file path.  Now, presumably i'll be able to install this in depending apps `A`, `B` and `C` and so on, and I can change my chart libary and all apps will reflect these changes.

The first thing I noticed is that I now have to `cd` into my chart library and run `npm run build` (which runs webpack) any time I change something, and then `cd` into the depending app I'm working on and run `npm i`.  This can perhaps be improved by using `npm link` but there are issues there as well (such as versioning and deploying to my server).  So my first question is about what a decent rapid development approach looks like now that my charting code is in a separate npm project.

The other problem I've noticed is that I've lost two valuable features with respect to my chart library code.  Code completion in VSCode and debugging in chrome dev tools.  I'm not sure why VSCode code completion has stopped working.  And for debugging, how would i be able to debug both my depending app and the library its depending on at the same time in chrome?

Comment: actually i've noticed a few things.  i can run `webpack --watch` to keep my library updating as i make edits (and this appears to be fast enough), and since i have source-maps turned on in my webpack config for the library, this appears to vend the source maps (enabling breakpoints) in the depending application (which has its own webpack config and source maps being generated).

Comment: and it seems like the code completion is working a bit more now so perhaps my project just got in a bad state.  i am still very much confused about the complexity around code reuse in the npm/webpack world, so any excellent wisdom in response to this would be greatly appreciated.  however, given the broadness of the question i might close it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `npm link`. It's immensely helpful when working on a library and its integration side by side.

Check the Chrome settings to make sure it's not instructed to skip libraries in `Settings` -> `Framework Blackboxing`, see e.g., http://blog.edenhauser.com/tell-chrome-debugger-to-ignore-libraries/.

Comment: for debugging, i did notice that the library webpack source maps are in devtools, just wasn't looking hard enough.

now say i use npm link, do you have a strategy for turning that off in production?  or is this something that requires some manual commands?